# Qooxdoo - celleditor problem with selectbox

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, qooxdoo, tablecelleditor

I've made table with celleditor similar to this:

http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/#table~Table_Cell_Editor.html

-row 'Status' with selectbox (I need to remember in this selectbox for items - name and ID).

But problem is like in this example - when I select an option and deactivate this editor (edit other row, or click somewhere else), and then return to edit it again, then it is selected other option than it was before - always first element on list.

I think it's a bug in qooxdoo (version 1.4.1), but do you have any solution for this (too keep correct element selected when I edit this cell again?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the standard solution to this problem is to keep a 'presentation model' of the user interface state. When the widget is shown again, you reconfigure it with the selection box showing the last used item or whatever you consider appropriate.